# First query string parameter is not parsed using qs npm package

Tags: javascript, query-string

I fail to parse the first query string parameter using the `qs` npm package. What am I doing wrong?

I execute these commands in my console

```
import * as qs from './qs'
var addr = "https://www.somesite.se/?title=querystring&action=edit"
var parsed = qs.parse(addr)
```

After executing these commands `parsed` has the value:

```
{ 'https://www.somesite.se/?title': 'querystring',
  action: 'edit' }
```

This is strange. Why is `title` not a property on the returned object? I would expect the value of `parsed.title` to be `'querystring'`. but it is not. The value of `parsed.title` is `undefined`.

Why?

Comment: Related: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`qs` parses query strings. It does not parse URLs. Use a URL parser (`new URL(addr).search.substring(1)`) to get the query string from the URL first.

`qs.parse("title=querystring&action=edit")` should give you a correct answer.

Now that I think about it... why even use `qs`? `new URL(addr).searchParams` should already give you the params parsed...

Comment: I got really excited about using searchParams, but unfortunately those appear to only be available in web workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams

Comment: @Lokua The page says it is available in Web Workers. It is not _only_ available in Web Workers. It is in Node, it is in regular JS, and _also_ in Web Workers. Try in all of those environments: `new URL("https://www.somesite.se/?title=querystring&action=edit").searchParams.get('action')` (except in weird browsers like IE).

Comment: Thank you @Amadan! I did not realize it was a map when I logged `new URL(...).searchParams` in the console it just looked like an empty object but expanding it I see it's a Map-like class.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is: the `qs` library is using for parsing the query string only.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

> a query string is the part of a uniform resource locator (URL) which assigns values to specified parameters.

For example:

[image]

In your case, the correct codes should be:

```
var addr = 'title=querystring&action=edit';
var parsed = qs.parse(addr);
console.log(parsed); // {title: "querystring", action: "edit"}
```

To bypass the leading question mark, use ignoreQueryPrefix:

```
var addr2 = '?title=querystring&action=edit';
var parsed2 = qs.parse(addr2, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true });
console.log(parsed2); // {title: "querystring", action: "edit"}
```

Hopefully, that helps!